# display name to the users insted of email in their inbox

Tags: php, email, sendmail, sendgrid

I am using `sendgrid` to send emails to my users. Previously it was working correctly, but from the last 10-20 days without any change in the code I noticed that the users see the email address instead of the name in their `from` field in the inbox.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'USERNAME';
$pass = 'PASSWORD';

$params = array(
'api_user'  => $user,
'api_key'   => $pass,
'to'        => 'example3@sendgrid.com',
'subject'   => 'testing from curl',
'html'      => 'testing body',
'text'      => 'testing body',
'from'      => '<domain name>example@sendgrid.com',  // see here 
 );
 $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

 // Generate curl request
 $session = curl_init($request);
 // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
 // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 // Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 // obtain response
 $response = curl_exec($session);
 url_close($session);

 // print everything out
 print_r($response);

 ?>
```

The problem is that users are supposed to get domain name instead of email in their `from` field in inbox but they are getting email.

I am using the `from` tag like this

```
     'from'      => '<domain name>example@sendgrid.com'
```

Can you suggest me something please?

Comment: A space between <name> and email address..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `fromname` param like:

```
'from' => 'email@domain.com',
'fromname' => 'Your Name'
```